# Buck controller MOSFET drive voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, constant-current, led-driver

I am trying to design a switching regulator for LEDs, which uses the LM3405 as controller. This IC uses the BOOST pin to power the internal MOSFET driver, which controls an internal MOSFET. There are few ways to derive this voltage, and in particular the proper way that I need is to derive this voltage from the output voltage. 
Here the circuit:

[image]

But I don't undesrtand how the gate driver can actually start at the beginning, while there is no output voltage. Maybe I miss something...

Here the basic schematic of the IC internal blocks:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the datasheet (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3405.pdf) pg 7:

"When the LM3405 starts up, internal circuitry from VIN supplies a 20mA current to the BOOST pin, flowing out of
the BOOST pin into C3. This current charges C3 to a voltage sufficient to turn the switch on."