# Buck converter as a LED driver with NO LOAD

Tags: led, inductor, buck, bootstrap

I am proceeding with a design of a LED driver using an LM3405.

I don't read anything related to what happens when the load is not present, on the datasheet. As you may have already read, this is the [configuration adopted](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211011/buck-controller-mosfet-drive-voltage).

But with open load, the output does not simply goes to Vin? When the MOS will turn off, the charge pump put Vin on the BOOST. If this is true, I will destroy the BOOST pin, which must no exceed the relative voltage between SW and BOOST pin of 5.5V!

Is there any sort of protection in the IC, something that I can implement additionally or something that I've even forgot? Are there any other issues related, except for the classical ones in literature about switching converters?

Comment: We are not here to read the datasheet to you.  Either this is answered in the datasheet where you can find it too, or it isn't, in which case we have no way of knowing for sure either.

Comment: Not at all. And moreover, if it is not written in datasheet one must not ask? Report this rule request on Meta. I made this question under the rules of StackExchange, nothing of opportunistic or lazy.

Comment: Olin: I think you may be being a bit harsh: Open LED protection is not something always specifically listed at manufacturers sites featuring controllers for these; even though there is an application note on the challenges of designing LED drivers linked to the part listed here, it makes no mention of open LED faults, which I see as something that I *commend* as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3405.pdf), I see no mention of [open LED protection](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt490/slyt490.pdf).

This is definitely something you should implement. Let me put it this way: *I would*.

As you have surmised, if there is no open circuit protection, it is highly likely that the boost converter can be destroyed if no LED is present.

Note that [this LED controller](http://www.linear.com/product/LT3492) specifically lists open LED protection.

Comment: But the datasheet does show several ways to limit the boost voltage.

Comment: I used an external source for the boost voltage. For the open load case, these pins are protected, and at the output will be the input voltage with not overvoltages, since there is almost no current in the inductor. Did I forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

That IC is not fully protected in this case. Basically, it wants the BOOST supply to be around 5 V. You can supply from VIN with some zeners if needed, or as you are doing from VOUT. But, if VOUT becomes open, the boost will increase as high as VIN.

Use one of the alternative configurations with a zener. You can also use a R & zener from VOUT to BOOST.